# Identify (and delete) all .gif files with more than 1 frame in all subdirectories

Tags: linux, unix, imagemagick, animated-gif

I having the following linux command to identify all .gif files and list its frames in the active directory:

```
identify -format '%n %i\n' -- *.gif
```

Now I want to modify and expand the command to fullfil the following:
1. indentify just the .gif files with MORE than 1 frame
2. look also in all subdirectories (right now the command is just looking at the active directory)
3. a command to:
a) list the identified files
b) delete the identified files

I would really appreciate you guys help to achieve this...

Thank you a lot in advance!!

Best,
Florian

Answer (score 1):

Your on the right path. I would recommend leveraging `find`, `sort` and `awk` commands to generate a list of files to remove.

```
find /path/to/directory \
     -type f \
     -name "*.gif" \
     -exec identify -format '%n %i\n' {} \; \
     | sort -u \
     | awk '$1 > 1 {print $2}'
```

How this works

- `find` will scan all sub-directors for file ending with `*.gif`, and pass the results to ImageMagick.
- `identify` will print the filename + frame count (what your already doing)
- `sort -u` will remove duplicate items (`uniq` utility will also work.)
- `awk` should print the second column (filename) if the first column (frame count) is greater than 1.

*note: this will not remove the files, but provide a list that can be inspected, and passed to `rm` command*

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I am getting strange results with this command :)

media: corrupt image `/is/htdocs/.......gif' @ error/gif.c/PingGIFImage/962.

Comment: Whoops. Looks like `find` utility found an invalid image. IM can't continue - so this solution wouldn't work :(